# Including single quotes from PostgreSQL in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have the following query that runs fine in PostgreSQL. When I try to run the same query in R (through PostgreSQL) it does not work, because the single quotes are not included.

I have already tried using `"'"day"'"` or `'day\'` but neither works.

```
Query <- dbGetQuery(con,'select
DATE_PART('day', to_timestamp("rollbackTime") - to_timestamp("commitTime")) as "Cancellation from payment')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can espace `'` with `\'`, so perhaps you are looking for:

```
sql <- 'select DATE_PART(\'day\', to_timestamp("rollbackTime") - to_timestamp("commitTime")) as "Cancellation from payment"'
Query <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

When debugging such strings, `cat` can be useful:

```
cat(sql)
```

will return

```
select DATE_PART('day', to_timestamp("rollbackTime") - to_timestamp("commitTime")) as "Cancellation from payment"
```